# Prettifying code instead code tags without modifying HTML

Tags: javascript, html, prettify

Is there a good JavaScript library to format and color highlight code with `<code>` tags which doesn't require me to modify the HTML in any way? I don't have control over the HTML, I can only add external JavaScript code. Of course, I could add external JavaScript code that does alter the HTML... but a simple JavaScript library that handles all that would be ideal.

***UPDATE***: I'm currently doing the following in every page to use google-code-prettify:

```
<script>
  var codes = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
  for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
    codes[i].className = 'prettyprint';
  }
</script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

I could use `className +=` but I know `<code>` tags won't have any other classes.

Comment: Why not simply use jQuery and add css rules to those elements?

Comment: Did you use a search engine?

Comment: @alex - JavaScript code within `<code>` tags can't be styled with CSS. @PhistucK - yes I did and I couldn't find much, maybe I'm not searching on the right terms. I found google-code-prettify (https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), but required adding a class to `<code>` tags.

Comment: But those `<code>` tags for javascript won't be rendered visible either way. So what are you trying to do? Get them rendered as normal html elements? The basic problem here is that they are outside of `<body>`, which could still render in modern browsers, but has undefined behaviour. Still, you could write a jQuery script that wraps those elements in other elements. I think it should even be possible to cut and paste them at different places in the html, but you said you did not wanted to do that. However, I doubt there exists a library for that, because of said problem.

Comment: Trying to understand what you wrote @alex, but having difficulty. I want something like this: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: Touché, I started to mix up the `<code>` tag with the `<script>` tag. It was late... But know I understand what you are trying to do. And I think the library you found yourself should happily do the trick. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use the library you found yourself (https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and have a little script of yours add the needed class to every `<code>` tag (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6jhf/9/)):

```
var myFunction = function()
{
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
    elements[i].className += "prettyprint";
  }
  window.PR.prettyPrint();
}
```

Notice that to call prettyPrint manually, one has to use the right scope: `window.PR.prettyPrint();`.

Comment: You just load the google-code-prettify JavaScript after the class additions like I have in my updated question

Comment: Glad that worked for you @at. To be sure, I'd still suggest to load the code with `autoload=false` and call your function including a call to `prettyPrint()` on e.g. `body.onload` to make absolutely sure that your code gets prettified. I am quite sure that there are quite some edge cases where prettyPrint or your script gets called to early. Better be safe than sorry.